# Random null response on dynamically created html elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom, addeventlistener

I'm receiving a very strange response from this code. My idea was:

1. To create 8 html elements mapping an array.
2. Selecting the `#cart-button` id to attach an `eventlistener` (click) and passing to it the id of the of the html element (I'm trying to obtain these values from the key attribute).

Sometimes in the console I'm obtaining all the results OK `(1 clicked, 2, clicked...)`, but sometimes the result is `null clicked`.

I'm trying to understand why this is happening. Thank you very much!

```js
// Product class

class Product {
  constructor(id, title, price, img) {
    this.id = id
    this.title = title
    this.price = price
    this.img = img
  }

  productCard = () => {
    return `<div class="w-full md:w-1/3 xl:w-1/4 p-6 flex flex-col" key=${this.id}><img class="hover:grow hover:shadow-lg cursor-pointer" src=${this.img}> <div class="pt-3 flex items-center justify-between"> <p class="">${this.title}</p> <svg class="cart-button h-6 w-6 fill-current text-gray-500 hover:text-black" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"> <path d="M12,4.595c-1.104-1.006-2.512-1.558-3.996-1.558c-1.578,0-3.072,0.623-4.213,1.758c-2.353,2.363-2.352,6.059,0.002,8.412 l7.332,7.332c0.17,0.299,0.498,0.492,0.875,0.492c0.322,0,0.609-0.163,0.792-0.409l7.415-7.415 c2.354-2.354,2.354-6.049-0.002-8.416c-1.137-1.131-2.631-1.754-4.209-1.754C14.513,3.037,13.104,3.589,12,4.595z M18.791,6.205 c1.563,1.571,1.564,4.025,0.002,5.588L12,18.586l-6.793-6.793C3.645,10.23,3.646,7.776,5.205,6.209 c0.76-0.756,1.754-1.172,2.799-1.172s2.035,0.416,2.789,1.17l0.5,0.5c0.391,0.391,1.023,0.391,1.414,0l0.5-0.5 C14.719,4.698,17.281,4.702,18.791,6.205z" /> </svg> </div> <p class="pt-1 text-gray-900">£${this.price}</p></div>`
  };
};

// Mock data

const ProductsList = [
  new Product(1, 'Minna', '9.99', 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1555982105-d25af4182e4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&h=400&q=80'),
  new Product(2, 'Palma', '109', 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508423134147-addf71308178?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&h=400&q=80'),
  new Product(3, 'Bergdis', '25.99', 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1449247709967-d4461a6a6103?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&h=400&q=80'),
  new Product(4, 'Danjal', '25', 'https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/LJIZlzHgQ7WPSh5KVTCB_Typewriter.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&h=400&q=80'),
  new Product(5, 'Kornus', '15', 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1467949576168-6ce8e2df4e13?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&h=400&q=80'),
  new Product(6, 'Redin', '9.99', 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544787219-7f47ccb76574?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&h=400&q=80'),
  new Product(7, 'Jensina', '167.99', 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550837368-6594235de85c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&h=400&q=80'),
  new Product(8, 'Steen', '13', 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1551431009-a802eeec77b1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&h=400&q=80'),
];

class HtmlHandler {
  constructor() {
    this.createHTMLCards();
    this.addTheListeners();
  }

  html = '';

  createHTMLCards() {
    ProductsList.forEach(product => this.html += product.productCard());
    // Create a new div element after the header
    const headerArea = document.querySelector('#products-area > nav');
    headerArea.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', this.html);
  }

  // Add a product to the cart
  addTheListeners() {
    const cartButton = document.querySelectorAll('.cart-button');

    cartButton.forEach((button) => {
      button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        const productId = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute('key');
        console.log(`${productId} clicked`);
      })
    })
  }

}

const htmlHandler = new HtmlHandler;
const product = new Product;
```

```css
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.work-sans {
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
}

#menu-toggle:checked+#menu {
  display: block;
}

.hover\:grow {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.hover\:grow:hover {
  transform: scale(1.02);
}

.carousel-open:checked+.carousel-item {
  position: static;
  opacity: 100;
}

.carousel-item {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0.6s ease-out;
}

#carousel-1:checked~.control-1,
#carousel-2:checked~.control-2,
#carousel-3:checked~.control-3 {
  display: block;
}

.carousel-indicators {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10;
}

#carousel-1:checked~.control-1~.carousel-indicators li:nth-child(1) .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-2:checked~.control-2~.carousel-indicators li:nth-child(2) .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-3:checked~.control-3~.carousel-indicators li:nth-child(3) .carousel-bullet {
  color: #000;
  /*Set to match the Tailwind colour you want the active one to be */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="favicon.svg" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@2.2.19/dist/tailwind.min.css" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:200,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Pure JS Shopping Cart</title>
</head>

<body>

  <body class="bg-white text-gray-600 work-sans leading-normal text-base tracking-normal">

    <!--Nav-->
    <nav id="header" class="w-full z-40 top-0 py-1 fixed bg-white">
      <div class="w-full container mx-auto flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between mt-0 px-6 py-3">

        <label for="menu-toggle" class="cursor-pointer md:hidden block">
          <svg class="fill-current text-gray-900" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20"
            viewBox="0 0 20 20">
            <title>menu</title>
            <path d="M0 3h20v2H0V3zm0 6h20v2H0V9zm0 6h20v2H0v-2z"></path>
          </svg>
        </label>
        <input class="hidden" type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle" />

        <div class="hidden md:flex md:items-center md:w-auto w-full order-3 md:order-1" id="menu">
          <nav>
            <ul class="md:flex items-center justify-between text-base text-gray-700 pt-4 md:pt-0">
              <li><a class="inline-block no-underline hover:text-black hover:underline py-2 px-4" href="#store">Shop</a>
              </li>
              <li><a class="inline-block no-underline hover:text-black hover:underline py-2 px-4" href="#about">About</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>

        <div class="order-1 md:order-2">
          <a class="flex items-center tracking-wide no-underline hover:no-underline font-bold text-gray-800 text-xl " href="#">
            <svg class="fill-current text-gray-800 mr-2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
              <path
                d="M5,22h14c1.103,0,2-0.897,2-2V9c0-0.553-0.447-1-1-1h-3V7c0-2.757-2.243-5-5-5S7,4.243,7,7v1H4C3.447,8,3,8.447,3,9v11 C3,21.103,3.897,22,5,22z M9,7c0-1.654,1.346-3,3-3s3,1.346,3,3v1H9V7z M5,10h2v2h2v-2h6v2h2v-2h2l0.002,10H5V10z" />
            </svg> PJSSC
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="order-2 md:order-3 flex items-center" id="nav-content">

          <a class="inline-block no-underline hover:text-black" href="#">
            <svg class="fill-current hover:text-black" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
              <circle fill="none" cx="12" cy="7" r="3" />
              <path
                d="M12 2C9.243 2 7 4.243 7 7s2.243 5 5 5 5-2.243 5-5S14.757 2 12 2zM12 10c-1.654 0-3-1.346-3-3s1.346-3 3-3 3 1.346 3 3S13.654 10 12 10zM21 21v-1c0-3.859-3.141-7-7-7h-4c-3.86 0-7 3.141-7 7v1h2v-1c0-2.757 2.243-5 5-5h4c2.757 0 5 2.243 5 5v1H21z" />
            </svg>
          </a>

          <button class="pl-3 inline-block no-underline hover:text-black" id="cart">
            <svg class="fill-current static hover:text-black" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24">
              <path
                d="M21,7H7.462L5.91,3.586C5.748,3.229,5.392,3,5,3H2v2h2.356L9.09,15.414C9.252,15.771,9.608,16,10,16h8 c0.4,0,0.762-0.238,0.919-0.606l3-7c0.133-0.309,0.101-0.663-0.084-0.944C21.649,7.169,21.336,7,21,7z M17.341,14h-6.697L8.371,9 h11.112L17.341,14z" />
              <circle cx="10.5" cy="18.5" r="1.5" />
              <circle cx="17.5" cy="18.5" r="1.5" />
            </svg>
            <div id="cart-number-badge"
              class="bg-red-500 rounded-full h-4 w-4 text-xs text-white absolute bottom-5 animate-pulse"></div>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="carousel relative container mx-auto" style="max-width:1600px;">
      <div class="carousel-inner relative overflow-hidden w-full">
        <!--Slide 1-->
        <input class="carousel-open" type="radio" id="carousel-1" name="carousel" aria-hidden="true" hidden="" checked="checked">
        <div class="carousel-item absolute opacity-0" style="height:50vh;">
          <div class="block h-full w-full mx-auto flex pt-6 md:pt-0 md:items-center bg-cover bg-right" style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1422190441165-ec2956dc9ecc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1600&q=80');">

            <div class="container mx-auto">
              <div class="flex flex-col w-full lg:w-1/2 md:ml-16 items-center md:items-start px-6 tracking-wide">
                <p class="text-black text-2xl my-4">Stripy Zig Zag Jigsaw Pillow and Duvet Set</p>
                <a class="text-xl inline-block no-underline border-b border-gray-600 leading-relaxed hover:text-black hover:border-black" href="#">view product</a>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <label for="carousel-3" class="prev control-1 w-10 h-10 ml-2 md:ml-10 absolute cursor-pointer hidden text-3xl font-bold text-black hover:text-white rounded-full bg-white hover:bg-gray-900 leading-tight text-center z-10 inset-y-0 left-0 my-auto">‹</label>
        <label for="carousel-2" class="next control-1 w-10 h-10 mr-2 md:mr-10 absolute cursor-pointer hidden text-3xl font-bold text-black hover:text-white rounded-full bg-white hover:bg-gray-900 leading-tight text-center z-10 inset-y-0 right-0 my-auto">›</label>

        <!--Slide 2-->
        <input class="carousel-open" type="radio" id="carousel-2" name="carousel" aria-hidden="true" hidden="">
        <div class="carousel-item absolute opacity-0 bg-cover bg-right" style="height:50vh;">
          <div class="block h-full w-full mx-auto flex pt-6 md:pt-0 md:items-center bg-cover bg-right" style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533090161767-e6ffed986c88?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjM0MTM2fQ&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1600&q=80');">

            <div class="container mx-auto">
              <div class="flex flex-col w-full lg:w-1/2 md:ml-16 items-center md:items-start px-6 tracking-wide">
                <p class="text-black text-2xl my-4">Real Bamboo Wall Clock</p>
                <a class="text-xl inline-block no-underline border-b border-gray-600 leading-relaxed hover:text-black hover:border-black" href="#">view product</a>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <label for="carousel-1" class="prev control-2 w-10 h-10 ml-2 md:ml-10 absolute cursor-pointer hidden text-3xl font-bold text-black hover:text-white rounded-full bg-white hover:bg-gray-900  leading-tight text-center z-10 inset-y-0 left-0 my-auto">‹</label>
        <label for="carousel-3" class="next control-2 w-10 h-10 mr-2 md:mr-10 absolute cursor-pointer hidden text-3xl font-bold text-black hover:text-white rounded-full bg-white hover:bg-gray-900  leading-tight text-center z-10 inset-y-0 right-0 my-auto">›</label>

        <!--Slide 3-->
        <input class="carousel-open" type="radio" id="carousel-3" name="carousel" aria-hidden="true" hidden="">
        <div class="carousel-item absolute opacity-0" style="height:50vh;">
          <div class="block h-full w-full mx-auto flex pt-6 md:pt-0 md:items-center bg-cover bg-bottom" style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519327232521-1ea2c736d34d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1600&q=80');">

            <div class="container mx-auto">
              <div class="flex flex-col w-full lg:w-1/2 md:ml-16 items-center md:items-start px-6 tracking-wide">
                <p class="text-black text-2xl my-4">Brown and blue hardbound book</p>
                <a class="text-xl inline-block no-underline border-b border-gray-600 leading-relaxed hover:text-black hover:border-black" href="#">view product</a>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <label for="carousel-2" class="prev control-3 w-10 h-10 ml-2 md:ml-10 absolute cursor-pointer hidden text-3xl font-bold text-black hover:text-white rounded-full bg-white hover:bg-gray-900  leading-tight text-center z-10 inset-y-0 left-0 my-auto">‹</label>
        <label for="carousel-1" class="next control-3 w-10 h-10 mr-2 md:mr-10 absolute cursor-pointer hidden text-3xl font-bold text-black hover:text-white rounded-full bg-white hover:bg-gray-900  leading-tight text-center z-10 inset-y-0 right-0 my-auto">›</label>

        <!-- Add additional indicators for each slide-->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li class="inline-block mr-3">
            <label for="carousel-1" class="carousel-bullet cursor-pointer block text-4xl text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-900">•</label>
          </li>
          <li class="inline-block mr-3">
            <label for="carousel-2" class="carousel-bullet cursor-pointer block text-4xl text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-900">•</label>
          </li>
          <li class="inline-block mr-3">
            <label for="carousel-3" class="carousel-bullet cursor-pointer block text-4xl text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-900">•</label>
          </li>
        </ol>

      </div>
    </div>

    <!--     
  Alternatively if you want to just have a single hero
  <section class="w-full mx-auto bg-nordic-gray-light flex pt-12 md:pt-0 md:items-center bg-cover bg-right" style="max-width:1600px; height: 32rem; background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1422190441165-ec2956dc9ecc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1600&q=80');">
    <div class="container mx-auto">
      <div class="flex flex-col w-full lg:w-1/2 justify-center items-start  px-6 tracking-wide">
        <h1 class="text-black text-2xl my-4">Stripy Zig Zag Jigsaw Pillow and Duvet Set</h1>
        <a class="text-xl inline-block no-underline border-b border-gray-600 leading-relaxed hover:text-black hover:border-black" href="#">products</a>
      </div>
      </div>
  </section>
  -->

    <section id="store" class="bg-white py-8">

      <div id="products-area" class="container mx-auto flex items-center flex-wrap pt-8 pb-12">

        <nav class="w-full z-30 top-0 px-6 py-1">
          <div class="w-full container mx-auto flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between mt-0 px-2 py-3">
            <a class="uppercase tracking-wide no-underline hover:no-underline font-bold text-gray-800 text-xl " href="#">
              Store
            </a>
            <div class="flex items-center" id="store-nav-content">
              <a class="pl-3 inline-block no-underline hover:text-black" href="#">
                <svg class="fill-current hover:text-black" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                  <path d="M7 11H17V13H7zM4 7H20V9H4zM10 15H14V17H10z" />
                </svg>
              </a>
              <a class="pl-3 inline-block no-underline hover:text-black" href="#">
                <svg class="fill-current hover:text-black" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                  <path
                    d="M10,18c1.846,0,3.543-0.635,4.897-1.688l4.396,4.396l1.414-1.414l-4.396-4.396C17.365,13.543,18,11.846,18,10 c0-4.411-3.589-8-8-8s-8,3.589-8,8S5.589,18,10,18z M10,4c3.309,0,6,2.691,6,6s-2.691,6-6,6s-6-2.691-6-6S6.691,4,10,4z" />
                </svg>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>

    </section>

    <section id="about" class="bg-white py-8">

      <div class="container py-10 px-6 mx-auto">

        <a class="uppercase tracking-wide no-underline hover:no-underline font-bold text-gray-800 text-xl mb-8" href="#">
          About
        </a>

        <p class="mt-8 mb-8">This template is inspired by the stunning nordic minamalist design - in particular:
          <br>
          <a class="text-gray-800 underline hover:text-gray-900" href="http://savoy.nordicmade.com/" target="_blank">Savoy Theme</a> created by <a class="text-gray-800 underline hover:text-gray-900" href="https://nordicmade.com/">https://nordicmade.com/</a>          and <a class="text-gray-800 underline hover:text-gray-900" href="https://www.metricdesign.no/" target="_blank">https://www.metricdesign.no/</a></p>

        <p class="mb-8">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <a href="#">random link</a> adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vel risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat. Vitae aliquet nec
          ullamcorper sit. Nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. In est ante in nibh mauris. Egestas congue quisque egestas diam in. Facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu. Nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat. Eget mi proin sed libero
          enim sed faucibus turpis in. Hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque. In aliquam sem fringilla ut. Gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui id. At tempor commodo
          ullamcorper a. Volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla. Vitae congue eu consequat ac.</p>

      </div>

    </section>

    <footer class="container mx-auto bg-white py-8 border-t border-gray-400">
      <div class="container flex px-3 py-8 ">
        <div class="w-full mx-auto flex flex-wrap">
          <div class="flex w-full lg:w-1/2 ">
            <div class="px-3 md:px-0">
              <h3 class="font-bold text-gray-900">About</h3>
              <p class="py-4">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas vel mi ut felis tempus commodo nec id erat. Suspendisse consectetur dapibus velit ut lacinia.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flex w-full lg:w-1/2 lg:justify-end lg:text-right">
            <div class="px-3 md:px-0">
              <h3 class="font-bold text-gray-900">Social</h3>
              <ul class="list-reset items-center pt-3">
                <li>
                  <a class="inline-block no-underline hover:text-black hover:underline py-1" href="#">Add social
                    links</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>

    // Cart Modal
    <div id="cart-modal" class="fixed top-16 right-10 w-60 h-auto bg-gray-50 shadow-xl rounded-lg z-50 hidden px-3 pt-3">
    </div>

  </body>
  <script type="module" src="./js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you share your markup? This isn't quite a [mcve]. Thanks. `querySelectorAll('#cart-button')` is very unusual. Ids must be unique, so the idea of selecting "all" (read: multiple) ids is nonsensical -- there's always exactly 0 or 1 of an id.

Comment: Thank you @ggorlen, I've tried to change the ID's with classes but the problem persist. I uploaded the code on codesandbox and you can see the problem and my markup. Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: Thanks @ggorlen, it makes sense. I added ta working snippet in the question. Thank you!

Comment: I improved a bit the formatting of my answer below, I hope it's clearer to read now ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem of **WHERE** the mouse click actually happens.

In your code, the `addTheListeners()` function attaches the event listener to the `<svg>` HTML elements, but each `<svg>` element has also a child `<path>` element.

When you click the button, the actual `e.target` of the click event will be either the `<svg>` or the `<path>`, depending on the exact position of the mouse cursor at the moment of the *click*.

Actually, the `<path>` line is very thin and difficult to click on, but it can definitely happen.

When the click hits the `<path>` rather than the `<svg>`, the `e.target.parentElement.parentElement` will **NOT** find the right `<div>` element with the *key* attribute but another HTML element (hence `getAttribute('key')` will be **null**).

To have a practical feedback, you can try to add a second `console.log(e.target)` to your listener. You will see that `null clicked` will be logged togheter with the `<path>` element; when the `e.target` is `<svg>` you will see the correct log `(1 clicked, 2 clicked...)`.

In cases like this, you should definitely use **event delegation** to catch the click correctly (regardless if it's on the `<svg>` or on the `<path>`).

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation
- https://javascript.info/event-delegation

Comment: Yes! That was the problem! I was obsessed with the code that generates the html and I forgot the most essential! I wrapped the `svg` with a `div`, added there the class and fixed the event callback with `e.currentTarget.parent...` instead of `e.target.parent...`. Thank you @cheesyMan!